# How can I escape the "|" in file names in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a list of files in the Linux file system. Some of them contains a "|" in the names.

How can I escape the "|" in a bash script to perform file operation (copy, move) in the for loop and do not interpret pipe?

In the script below, any file name with "|" is interpreted as a pipe command.
Where file_list is a text file with those names.

```
IFS=$'\n' 
for file_name in $(cat ${file_list})
do
    mkdir -p "${destination_directory}/@${file_name}"
    cd "${source_directory}/@${file_name}/"
    cp -vR * "${destination_directory}/@${file_name}/"
    cd ../
done
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that could interpret "`|`" in filenames as a shell pipe; is this being run in some unusual way? I'd put `set -x` before the problem section to see what bash thinks is happening as it runs, and see what's different from what you expect. (Note: the `set -x` trace tends to put single-quotes around arguments that contain any funny characters -- like "`|`" -- to indicate that they don't have their special meaning, and are just acting like plain characters). I'd also recommend using a [`while read` loop instead of `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Inside quotes the pipe character is ignored.  The only place you don't quote your variables is in the `for` line.